# Recommendations for visual web page designing tools for Mac

Tags: osx, web-development, graphic-design

I'm looking for software for the Mac that is specifically designed for visual designers of websites.

I'm not looking for heavy duty image editors like PhotoShop as I don't need to process photography or anything like that.

I'm also not looking for software that has any sort of website building capabilities as I'll be doing the build myself.

Things I need the software to do:

- manipulate layers
- manage SVGs
- export bits as various graphical assets
- manage fonts
- handle texture overlays
- be easy for a beginner to get their head around
- easy export of font / colour / gradient css would be nice

It doesn't really need to do anything that isn't transferable to a website without the use of images.

I've PhotoShop (way too much for web design) and GIMP (insanely frustrating UX issues) for various jobs during my time as a front end developer so neither of these are viable options.

I've used Sketch at work and it seems reasonable, but my Googling is throwing up far too many full website building solutions so I'm asking the community what they would recommend. Sketch is of course a good answer and perhaps comes with the benefit of being able to ask colleagues if I'm stuck.

I do have some money for this, but wouldn't want to spend more than $100 for a single license. I'm not a business, this will be for personal projects.

Comment: You may want to give [Macaw](http://macaw.co/) a try. Btw it's free now! :)